# mysqli fetch_array() is only turning first row of retrieved data into an array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

What seems to be happening is **$result_tag** is only holding the first row of the sql data retrieved.

When I run the result **query** on SQl in returns a table with multiple rows.
However, when I **var_dump()** it, it only returns the first row and nothing else.

```
  while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {    
  echo ....stuff that dont matter

  //Now I want some SQL results based on a result from ^^^ $row['ID']
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT tags.Tag FROM tags WHERE tags.results_ID =".$row['ID'] );
  $result_tag = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); 

  //I got the results. Now I want to compare them to another array '$explode' 
  //and echo out elements that are the same

    foreach($explode as $explodeValue){
      foreach($result_tag as $tag){
        if($tag == $explodeValue){
          echo $explodeValue;
        }
      }
    }

}//end of 1st while
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `fetch_all();` `fetch_array()` returns just one row (as an array)
See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

This is in fact what the outermost while is doing, fetching one row at a time with `fetch_array()`

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE results_ID =".$row['ID'] );
```